# Setting up Two's Complement in Binary

Tags: binary, twos-complement

you can either flip the bits and add 1 or add 1 then flip the bits.

In two's complements, can you add 1 and then the flip the bits or can you only flip the bits and then add 1? Or do I have it mixed up?

Answer (score 0):

Those two methods will not give the same result.

Consider `00000000`. If you flip the bits first, you get `00000000`, which is sensible.

However, if you add 1 first, you get `11111110`, which is obviously not.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. Take the binary number `10`. 
If you add one you get `11` and its one's complement is `00`.

If you compute the one's complement first you get `01` and when you add one it's `10`, which differs from `00`.